# Распарсить массив из json

Tags: javascript

Есть json файл с названием example.json

```
{
    "name":"John",
    "age":31,
    "pets":[
        { "animal":"dog", "name":"Fido" },
        { "animal":"cat", "name":"Felix" },
        { "animal":"hamster", "name":"Lightning" }
    ]
}
```

Пытаюсь вывести названия животных

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.name + "," + myObj.pets;
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "example.json", true);
xmlhttp.send();
</script>
```

На выходе получаю

> John,[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

А как получить такое
Имя: Джон,
Животные:
Собака - Фидо, Кот-Феликс, Хомяк - Лайтнинг.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно в строку массив питомцев преобразовать. Как-то так:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.name + ", Животные: " + myObj.pets.map(pet => pet.animal + " - " + pet.name).join(',');
```